# Autocompleting a form in PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli, autocomplete

I have been trying to make an autocomplete script for the whole day but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="number" id="firstfield">

  <input type="text" id="text_first">
  <input type="text" id="text_sec">
  <input type="text" id="text_third">

</form>
```

This is my html.
what I am trying to do is to use ajax to autocomplete the first field 
like this: [image: preview]

and when there are 9 numbers in the first input it fills the other inputs as well with the correct linked data

the script on the ajax.php sends a mysqli_query to the server and asks for all the 
   data(table: fields || rows: number, first, sec, third)

Comment: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Comment: That is not what I meant, the example you gave me has an list and it doesn't complete the input like in the image

Comment: It does exactly that.

Comment: nope, you still have to click the result below the input to complete it.

Comment: You can press the tab key to complete it. If you fill in the text automatically then the user will have to delete it to keep typing if it doesn't match. Anyways, just thought I would offer an alternative to reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2

PHP Integration Example:

```
<?php
/* add your db connector in bootstrap.php */
require 'bootstrap.php';

/*
$('#categories').select2({
    placeholder: 'Search for a category',
    ajax: {
        url: "/ajax/select2_sample.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 100,
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                term: term, //search term
                page_limit: 10 // page size
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            return { results: data.results };
        }

    },
    initSelection: function(element, callback) {
        return $.getJSON("/ajax/select2_sample.php?id=" + (element.val()), null, function(data) {

                return callback(data);

        });
    }

});
*/

$row = array();
$return_arr = array();
$row_array = array();

if((isset($_GET['term']) && strlen($_GET['term']) > 0) || (isset($_GET['id']) &&      is_numeric($_GET['id'])))
{

if(isset($_GET['term']))
{
    $getVar = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
    $whereClause =  " label LIKE '%" . $getVar ."%' ";
}
elseif(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $whereClause =  " categoryId = $getVar ";
}
/* limit with page_limit get */

$limit = intval($_GET['page_limit']);

$sql = "SELECT id, text FROM mytable WHERE $whereClause ORDER BY text LIMIT $limit";

/** @var $result MySQLi_result */
$result = $db->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {

        while($row = $result->fetch_array())
        {
            $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
            $row_array['text'] = utf8_encode($row['text']);
            array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
        }

    }
}
else
{
    $row_array['id'] = 0;
    $row_array['text'] = utf8_encode('Start Typing....');
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

$ret = array();
/* this is the return for a single result needed by select2 for initSelection */
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $ret = $row_array;
}
/* this is the return for a multiple results needed by select2
* Your results in select2 options needs to be data.result
*/ 
else
{
    $ret['results'] = $return_arr;
} 
echo json_encode($ret);

$db->close();
```

Legacy Version: 
In my example i'm using an old Yii project, but you can easily edit it to your demands.

The request encodes in JSON. (You don't need yii for this tho)

```
public function actionSearchUser($query) {
    $this->check();
    if ($query === '' || strlen($query) < 3) {
        echo CJSON::encode(array('id' => -1));
    } else {
        $users = User::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'userID',
            'condition' => 'username LIKE :username',
            'limit' => '5',
            'params' => array(':username' => $query . '%')
        ));
        $data = array();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $data[] = array(
                'id' => $user->userID,
                'text' => $user->username,
            );
        }
        echo CJSON::encode($data);
    }

    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Using this in the View:

```
$this->widget('ext.ESelect2.ESelect2', array(
'name' => 'userID',
'options' => array(
    'minimumInputLength' => '3',
    'width' => '348px',
    'placeholder' => 'Select Person',
    'ajax' => array(
        'url' => Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('API/searchUser'),
        'dataType' => 'json',
        'data' => 'js:function(term, page) { return {q: term }; }',
        'results' => 'js:function(data) { return {results: data}; }',
    ),
),
```

));

The following Script is taken from the official documentation, may be easier to adopt to:

```
$("#e6").select2({
        placeholder: {title: "Search for a movie", id: ""},
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
            url: "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term, // search term
                    page_limit: 10,
                    apikey: "ju6z9mjyajq2djue3gbvv26t" // please do not use so this example keeps working
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to alter remote JSON data
                return {results: data.movies};
            }
        },
        formatResult: movieFormatResult, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
        formatSelection: movieFormatSelection  // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    });
```

This may be found here: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select-2.1.html

You can optain a copy of select2 on the github repository above.